# what "Weborb for .NET" version am I *really* running?

Tags: .net, weborb

the header on my console says v4.1.0.0, but I would swear I had previously installed v4.1.0.1, but that WAS a while ago, and now I'd like to be certain I've upgraded.  Anybody know a way to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weborb install directory will show the version (C:\Program Files\WebORB for .NET\4.1.0.0).

The weborb uninstaller will tell you what version it is un-installing.

And... The release notes (C:\Program Files\WebORB for .NET\4.1.0.0\readme.txt ) show the version as well  [WebORB for .NET, version 4.1.0.1].

If none of these show you the version, try dancing around the room with three candles burning chanting incantations in Objective C.

Comment: Mistake: In the release notes, I meant to say they will show the version [WebORB for .NET, version 4.1.0.0].  That is, of course, the version we expect it to show, being that it is in the WebORB for .NET\4.1.0.0 directory.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to test what version of weborb your site is running is to hit the 'diagnostics.aspx' file in your browser. It will tell you exactly what assembly version you are running, the version of the weborb.config, as well as a list of other dependencies and their versions.